# How do I hide the table id of a Fusion Table so the user cannot see the source of the fusion table layer on a Google Map?

Tags: asp.net, google-maps, google-fusion-tables

I am using Fusion Tables to add a FusionTablesLayer to my Google Map that shows some markers. I do not want the user to know where the data is coming from (ie: Fusion Table Id).

How can I hide the table id from the user? Currently it is located in JavaScript:

```
        var tableId = "not_hidden_from_user";
        var layer = new google.maps.FusionTablesLayer({
            map: map,
            heatmap: { enabled: false },
            query: {
                select: "col12",
                from: tableId,
                where: ""
            }
        });
```

I know that Google needs to access the Fusion Table but I was hoping there was a way to keep the source from the user. The goal is to filter the Fusion Table and show only certain markers to certain users. I am using ASP.Net.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes the simpler solution is the best. Instead of cracking your head looking for way to hide the table,  I suggest to consider to obfuscate the entire javascript file.  I am  using this service:  https://javascriptobfuscator.com without any problem. But you can test also:

http://www.danstools.com/javascript-obfuscate/
http://javascript2img.com/